# PHP script not adding rows in MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently working on my website's login/register page but the issue I'm having is that the PHP script isn't adding rows into the database. I've been trying to figure this problem out for a few days but I haven't come up with a solution. There are no errors present on the page upon submission either...

```
<?php

    mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("test") or die(mysql_error());

    if(isset($_POST['f_name']) && !empty($_POST['f_name']) && 
       isset($_POST['l_name']) && !empty($_POST['l_name']) && 
       isset($_POST['reg_email']) && !empty($_POST['reg_email']) && 
       isset($_POST['conf_email']) && !empty($_POST['conf_email']) && 
       isset($_POST['password']) && !empty($_POST['password']) && 
       $_POST['birthday-day'] != 0 && 
       $_POST['birthday-month'] != 0 && 
       $_POST['birthday-year'] != 0) 
    {

    $f_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['f_name']);
    $l_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['l_name']);
    $reg_email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['reg_email']);
    $conf_email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['conf_email']);
        $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
    $b_day = $_POST['birthday-day'];
    $b_month = $_POST['birthday-month'];
    $b_year = $_POST['birthday-year'];

    $search = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email='".$reg_email."'");
    $match = mysql_num_rows($search);

    if($reg_email !== $conf_email) {

        $msg = "The emails dont match.";

    }

    if (!preg_match("^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$^", $reg_email)) {

        $msg = "The email you have entered is invalid. Please try again.";
    }

    if ($match > 0) {

        $msg = "Email address already registered. Please enter a different one.";
    } else {

        mysql_query("INSERT INTO userstest (f_name, l_name, email, password) VALUES(
            '".$f_name."',
    '".$l_name."',
    '".$reg_email."',
    '".$password."') ") or die(mysql_error());

        }

}

else {

    //code

}
```

Form...

```
<form name="register" action="<?php print ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post" class="regform" >

    <input type="text" name="f_name" class="f_name" placeholder="First Name" />
    <input type="text" name="l_name" class="l_name" placeholder="Last Name" />
    <input type="text" name="reg_email" class="reg_email" placeholder="Email" />
    <input type="text" name"conf_email" class="conf_email" placeholder="Re-enter Email" />
    <input type="password" name="password" class="reg_pass" placeholder="Password" />

    <div id="birthday">

        <h1>
            BIRTHDAY
        </h1>

        <select name="birthday-day" id="day" class="day">

            <option value="0">Day</option>
            <option value="01">1</option>
            <option value="02">2</option>
            <option value="03">3</option>
            <option value="04">4</option>
            <option value="05">5</option>
            ...etc


        </select>

        <select name="birthday-month" class="month">

            <option value="0">Month</option>
            <option value="01">Jan</option>
            <option value="02">Feb</option>
            <option value="03">Mar</option>
            <option value="04">Apr</option>

        </select>

        <select name="birthday-year" class="year">

            <option value="0">Year</option>
            <option value="1994">1994</option>

        </select>

    </div>

    <div id="submitbutton">

        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="reg_submit" value="REGISTER" />

    </div>

</form>
```

It may be a simple syntax error I'm not seeing but I appreciate any help I get.

Comment: Just for you to know, `mysql_ functions` are deprecated and should be replaced with newer methodologies like [mysqli_](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) etc.

Comment: Please note that mysql_* functions are depreacted. Please have a look at mysqli_* or PDO

Comment: Double check that the table name and column names are correct.

Comment: Also, you're using the `users` table for checking the username and then inserting into the `userstest` table. Shouldn't it be the `users` table?

Comment: yeah you're right but that isn't the issue unfortunately SeanWM

Comment: Please don't store passwords in plain text. See the [PHP password hashing best practice](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php#faq.passwords.bestpractice) and [`hash_pbkdf2()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-pbkdf2.php).

Comment: I won't be Tomas, this is just the base script, I'll be adding to it as soon as this works. I'm keeping it simple to keep errors low, and then I'll be adding encryption from there

Comment: Have you checked to see if it's really getting to the `mysql_query("INSERT INTO userstest (` part? You can try debugging at that point, first to be sure it's actually getting there, and then to check exactly what the SQL string contains.

Comment: How might I go about doing that @tiredpixel ?

Comment: @user2693852, There are many ways - one would be to comment out that query part entirely, and write a new `$msg` in that part of the `if` (just like the others). We're expecting it to display that message, similar to if the email had already been registered.

Comment: Ok I'll give that a go. Also i've just noticed that the $msg is never set? It never displays on my page so does this mean the whole if statement doesn't work?

Comment: @user2693852, Well, not sure about the rest of your code, but all it means in the part you posted is that it hasn't gone into the 'emails don't match' or the 'invalid email' or the 'already registered' parts. But you can always debug with adding some `die()` messages or similar.

Comment: Added $msg="doesnt enter if statement" in the last else statement. which means that the script doesn't enter the if statement. Means the if statement is wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: Catch the result of mysql_query and make sure it's false (if not the problem is elsewhere). Check if the case of the table and column names is correct. As a side suggestion, if someone tries to register with an email already in the database, they most likely forgot their password, so it's better to help them recover it instead of creating a new account.

Comment: @Sylverdrag the script doesnt actually enter the if statement, pointing to the fact that the conditions may be wrong but i can't see any issues with them... Really confused with this one

Comment: @user2693852 Just before that condition, do echo "<pre>"; print_r($_POST). This will let you check that the keys and values are exactly what you expect. The slightest typo will result in a variable not set and fail the if condition. For housekeeping purposes, you can get rid of all the "isset()" conditions since empty() also covers that case (if a var is not set, empty() returns true).

Comment: @Sylverdrag Done as you said "<pre>"; print_r($_POST);... all of the keys/values are setting correctly, and I also removed the "isset()"'s. What does this mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is my original answer, which spawned the thread that led to the answer. Since this won't help many people looking for a solution, this will make things clearer:

At the top of the form, after it has been displayed but *before* it has been submitted, add this code:

```
    $super_test = (
        isset($_POST['f_name'])     && !empty($_POST['f_name']) 
    &&  isset($_POST['l_name'])     && !empty($_POST['l_name']) 
    &&  isset($_POST['reg_email'])  && !empty($_POST['reg_email']) 
    &&  isset($_POST['conf_email']) && !empty($_POST['conf_email']) 
    &&  isset($_POST['password'])   && !empty($_POST['password']) 
    &&  $_POST['birthday-day'] != 0 
    &&  $_POST['birthday-month'] != 0 
    &&  $_POST['birthday-year'] != 0
    ) ;

    dump($_POST);
    die(dump($super_test));
```

This immediately showed a missing field in the $_POST variable (conf_email) which was then narrowed down to a missing '=' sign in this case.

And the magic function `dump()` was nicked from @PhilSturgeon:

```
function dump()
{
    list($callee) = debug_backtrace();
    $arguments = func_get_args();
    $total_arguments = count($arguments);

    echo '<fieldset style="background: #fafafa !important; border:2px cornflowerblue solid; padding:6px; font-size: 10px;">';
    echo '<legend style="background:lightgrey; padding:5px;">'.$callee['file'].' @ line: '.$callee['line'].'</legend><pre>';

    $i = 0;
    foreach ($arguments as $argument)
    {
        echo '<br/><strong>Debug #'.(++$i).' of '.$total_arguments.'</strong>: ';

        if ( (is_array($argument) || is_object($argument)) && count($argument))
        {
            print_r($argument);
        }
        else
        {
            var_dump($argument);
        }
    }

    echo '</pre>' . PHP_EOL;
    echo '</fieldset>' . PHP_EOL;
}
```

-- end of summary --

---

You have

```
$reg_email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['reg_email']);
```

and then you have

```
$search = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email='".$reg_email."'");
```

It's possible that the query never matches because something is happening the $reg_email that makes it a different value from the database column.

At any rate I would:

- add a line under the `mysql_select` that read `die(print_r($_POST))` to see what was coming from the input page (first debug step)
- add a line before `if match ...` to `echo $msg` because it's possible it's being overwritten.
- I would split the query building into two phases and force an output there as well, and I would move it above the `if ($match` so that you can see the query always regardless of the logic:

  $query = "INSERT INTO userstest (f_name, l_name, email, password) VALUES(
          '".$f_name."',
  '".$l_name."',
  '".$reg_email."',
  '".$password."') ";
  echo $query;
  mysql_query($query) ...

Comment: Hi stephen, none of these debugging steps working because it seems that the conditions of the if statement are wrong and dont match. The script never actually enters the if statement and the $msg variable is never set, hence the mysql queries also don't run. Any ideas as to why this might be?

Comment: If it's not going into the very first `if` statement, then you need to see what's coming in the $_POST. Put the first line of code as:

    `die(print_r($_POST))`

Comment: And at a guess, I'd say the values from the birthday fields are not matching correctly - 'blank' versus 0

Comment: Just done that, all of the keys/values match corrently, even the birthday ones

Comment: Let's double-check it all: split it into

$check = if(... statement);
echo $check;
if ($check) { ...

Also, maybe you could add an `echo` to the `else` clause above.

Comment: Also, could you post your actual form?

Comment: Attempted to do what you said, didn't really change anything, nothing different happened. Also I added an echo in the else statement, that works. it seems it just completely misses the if statement and goes right to the else...

Comment: Well, if the `if` statement isn't working, then the field don't match up, even if it looks like they do. I would split them up and check the individual parts one at a time:

$test1 = isset($_POST['f_name']) && !empty($_POST['f_name'];
echo $test1 ? '1 true' : '1 false';

And so on, before getting to the actual `if`. All this is assuming that the error is not the mysql stuff at the start. And again - can you show the form that this is posting from?

Comment: Your conf_email isn't in the $_POST. You forgot an =. 

    name="conf_email"

Comment: yep, you found it. Such a rookie mistake, now it works. How do I go ahead and give you reputation?